# Show that a squence converges to the same limit under two different metrics

Tags: metric-spaces

Show that a sequence $\{x_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges to a limit $\lambda$ under the metric $\rho(x, y) = \sqrt{|x-y|}$ if and only if it converges to $\lambda$ under the absolute value metric $d(x, y) = |y − x|$.

How do I show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$ \rho(x_k, \lambda)^2=d(x_k, \lambda).$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists n_0(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $k \ge n_0$. $\implies \rho(x_k, \lambda) < \epsilon$. Since, $d(x_k, \lambda) = p^2(x_k, \lambda) < \epsilon^2$ then if $\forall \epsilon^2 >0$ there does not exist $n_0(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $k \ge n_0$. Then $\forall \epsilon >0$ there can't exist $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $k \ge n_0$

Comment: Above is my attempt at proceeding. Is this correct?